# WebRequest.BeginGetResponse does not work asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have C# code and have a problem with **webRequest.begingetresponse**.

When I try to used it for *asynchronous call*, the working thread is blocked and waits for the callback to be called. But, as I read in documentation, the current thread should continue to run and the callback method should be invoked by a different thread once the response is back from the server.

[**UPDATE**] Actually getting the response back from the server is where the current thread is blocked, and when I check the thread IDs, the thread which calls the callback is the same thread who sent the request.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
public class MyRequestState
{

    public WebRequest Request;
    public WebResponse Response;
    public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public MyRequestState()
    {

        Request = null;
        Response = null;
    }
}


public class SendRequest
{
    private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    { 
     //do sth ... 
     state.Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
     //do sth ...
     state.allDone.Set();
    }
    public void MakeWebRequestAsync(string url)
    {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     request.Method = "GET";
     request.Proxy = null;
     state state = new MyRequestState();
     state.Request = request;

     IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse(new    System.AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), state);

     state.allDone.WaitOne();
    }
```

}

Comment: Is this in silverlight? I had this exact problem in silverlight because although the calls are async, the begin and end getResponse are all done on the same thread, which is why you are blocked indefinitely. It does beg the question, why are you trying to make the async call synchronous?

Comment: Can you give more background? What kind of application is this code running in? Is it console app, silverlight, service process etc? Also, what version of the framework? What is the URL that you are hitting?

Answer (score 0):

WebRequest.BeginGetResponse wait for connection synchronously and then receive data asynchronously. If the connection takes some times, it will freeze the calling thread for a while.

Comment: Actually getting the response back from the server is where the current thread is blocked, and when I check the thread IDs, the thread which calls the callback is the same thread who sent the request.

Comment: Could you post some more information (or links to sources) where one could learn more about this? If BeginGetResponse is supposed to wait for the connection, what is its purpose? How can the waiting for connection be handled asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting on your ManualResetEvent right after starting the request. That's why your thread blocks. The thread isn't being signaled to continue until your completed callback is called.

Comment: When I trace the code, call stack shows that I am blocked at beginGetResponse, and it doesn't even hit state.allDone.WaitOne(); After a while, it hits the callback and then state.allDone.WaitOne().                                          Also I checked the CompletedSynchronously property of the result, it is always true. what about thread ID? The same thread calls the request and the callback.